# What could cause EasyEclipse to terminate with error window?

Tags: eclipse

When I start EasyEclipse, I get error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
```

Do you have any idea as to the possible cause for this kind of error message?

Answer (score 0):

If this happen right from the start, it may be related to your `eclipse.ini` content.

See [this one (for Eclipse 3.6 Helios)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659),
and check the end of each lines of your `eclipse.ini`: there should be no extra space.

After that, it depends on:

- the exact Eclipse version
- the exact JVM used to launch said Eclipse
- your platform (OS)

See for instance [bug 174642](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=174642).